# Converting old html tables to responsive

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a 10 year old website and everything is built using tables. Due to recent change in ranking of sites by Google i want to make this website responsive from tables. The header, left menu, content, right menu, footer are built using table tr and td.

I want a quick solution to convert all the tables to responsive css on a fly. i don't want to make major changes to website breaking the site design.

I would like the left menu to disappear on responsive small screens and display content to full width and also boxes to collapse 1 per row.

The sample code is below.

http://jsfiddle.net/1atrsoaq/

I am open to jquery/css solutions.

```
<body>
<table  class="responsive" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tbody><tr> 
    <td colspan="3"> 
        <h1>Logo</h1>

</td></tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#66ccff"> 
    <td colspan="3">&nbsp; 
  </td></tr>
  <tr> 
    <td bgcolor="#66ccff" valign="top" width="16%"> 
       <table class="responsive-lmenu" width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">


   <tr> 
    <td class="menus"><a href="/antigua-citizenship.htm">Menu 1</a></td>
  </tr>

           <tr> 
    <td class="menus"><a href="/antigua-citizenship.htm">Menu 2</a></td>
  </tr>
           <tr> 
    <td class="menus"><a href="/antigua-citizenship.htm">Menu 3</a></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
      <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
    <td class="main" valign="top" width="68%"><p>&nbsp;</p>

      <table class="responsive" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" width="100%">
        <tbody>




          <tr valign="top"> 
          <td class="mainbox"><h1 align="center">Box 1</h1>


                <p align="center"><strong>Minimum Details</strong></p>
            <ul>

              <li>Line one</li>
              <li>Line two for the content</li>

            </ul> 

            </td>
          <td class="mainbox"><h1 align="center">Box 2</h1>
            <ul>
                <li>Line one</li>
              <li>Line two for the content</li>
            </ul>
           </td>
        </tr>


        <tr valign="top"> 
          <td class="mainbox"><h1 align="center">Box 3</h1>
            <div align="center">
            </div>
            <p align="center">Citizenship by Investment</p>
                <p align="center">Real Estate Investment</p>
            <ul>
              <li>Line one</li>
              <li>Line two for the content</li>
            </ul>
      </td>

          <td class="mainbox"><h1 align="center">Box 4</h1>
            <p align="center">Header</p>
            <ul>
              <li>Line 1</li>
              <li>Line 1</li>
              <li>Line 3 </li>
            </ul>
        </tr>



        </tbody><tbody>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>

      <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
    <td valign="top" width="16%">
    <br>
</td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <td colspan="3"><p align="center">&nbsp;</p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>

</body>
```

Comment: I think you need to re-create the site. Anything that old with that kind of code is seriously out of date.

Comment: Not sure if it would work - but try wrapping your table in a div with class table-responsive and including bootstrap.css

Answer (score 1):

This can be done, but it will take a significant amount of work. Is your website a couple of static pages, or is it part of a larger site run/hosted by a CMS (content management system)?

Assuming it is a few static pages, I would suggest taking a look at Bootstrap. It is a responsive framework, that will do a lot of the heavy lifting for you, without requiring you to write hundred's of media queries. http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_css_tables.asp

Also what google is looking at for a "responsive site" is the headers on the page. Make sure after you are done with your refreshed code, you apply the meta information:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Also I would suggest once you are done, go into google's webmaster tools, and have them re-index your site, so you are not waiting on google to spider your site again.

Good luck.

Comment: Sorry it cut off the meta information: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: The site has about 30 pages poorly coded. Need a quick solution, dont want to start from the scratch. I am sure there are css and jquery experts out there.

Comment: Sorry bootstrap is not responsive, horizontal scroll bars appear and doesnt help much.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with other commenters that it would be best to rewrite the site with new standards. Speaking from experience, though, it's not always the most practical. If you have a large site that isn't using templates, it can become a time-consuming and burdensome project. A possibility is a temporary fix that will hold you over while recoding the site. I'm not completely sure if this fix will fix your search engine rating, though, as the current layout cannot be fixed with CSS alone.

You'll need to use JS to break `.responsive-lmenu` out of the main table and put it in it's own div at the top of a page (below the logo). The existing table can be left as-is, with some media query to change it's display to inline-block.

See here for example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1atrsoaq/1/

EDIT: Here is a revised fiddle that will play nicely with IE9 (and I'm hoping most other browsers; will test more when I get a chance): http://jsfiddle.net/1atrsoaq/5/. This script takes the `.main .responsive td` elements, converts them to divs, then puts them in their own `<td>` for proper rendering. It also strips some other `<tr>` that cause the content to display incorrectly.

Comment: Seems convincing :J i will test it and will get back to you soon.

Comment: @pbu I have been tinkering on IE9 (don't have Safari installed on this machine) with little success.. I'll keep trying. It seems like some browsers don't like us modifying <td> displays. Might need to use jQuery to change the elements entirely.

Comment: @pbu I updated my answer. Let me know if this does the trick.